# Retrieving Data from Database which was entered from a drop down menu: data is showing as numeric

Tags: sql-server, database, drop-down-menu, data-retrieval

I'm trying to retrieve data using SQL that was entered into a database using a drop down menu box.
The values from the box are things link "cap", "coupon", "liner" etc.

But when I try to retrieve the data from its location in the database (MaterialPackaging.Packaging) the value comes out as numeric.

ex: where it should be 'cap', it gives 12, 'tray' is 7, etc...

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it (preferrably without using some switch statement as a key of sorts) is there some sort of conversion that is going on here that I can change? Is this something partial to drop down menus?

Comment: perhaps your database has a lookup table for the various values, that you could join into your query?

Comment: I don't see a lookup table for this, but thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Okay, your question is very vague.**

What language and/or platform are you using?

Is it a ASPX form or a C# windows form?

Both allow drop downs to have values (1, 2, ..) associated with them.

Go to the source my friend!

**Use SSMS, query the data table and see what the values are.  Maybe you are storing numeric instead of text strings.**

***If you really need text, please join to a decode table and return the text value that you want.***

That way, you do not need to code a case statement on the front end!

Comment: I'm using an rdl report to return the values-- the data itself is entered through a management website that I am not trained in. SQL Server Management also shows numeric values.

Comment: Edit** Thank you-- I'm unfamiliar with decode tables; is there anything I should know?

Comment: A decode or look-up table are one in the same.  For each numeric code, have a text value in the table.  Join the original data to the decode table on the numeric code.  Just return the text value.  This avoids case statements when showing the detail content on the report.  For filtering, you will have to return back the numeric to SQL Server.  Good luck with your SSRS report ...